What is the reason behind the fourth axiom in Gödel's ontological proof?
In Gödel's ontological proof, axiom 4 goes like this:

And I'm not sure about what it means. If that P(φ) is true, then isn't it necessarily true as well? There's some basic concept about modal logic I can't grasp.
In short, what is the substancial difference between p and □p? Can you provide an example where p ⇒ □p does not hold?
THanks in advance.

@DavidGudeman yes, it's an axiom: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_ontological_proof#Symbolic_notation
I was able to understand all of the steps pretty easily, except for this one. P(ϕ) means "ϕ is a positive property".

Wikipedia explains what this means and what it is for in the discussion above the symbolic proof: "Requiring positive properties being positive in every possible world (axiom 4), Gödel can show that Godlikeness is an essence of a Godlike object (theorem 3)." In other words, he postulates that if a property φ is positive in the actual world then it is necessarily positive, i.e. stays positive in every possible world.

Now I'm confused about the reason why he proves □∃x : G(x), when just proving ∃x : G(x) would be sufficient to show God's existence.

Because many theists want to argue that God exists necessarily, not just as an accidental contingency in the actual world. This was the original ambition of the ontological argument. Here is the SEP discussion of Gödel’s argument that may give you additional insights.

There are a couple of different versions of the proof.
Wrt Wiki, we have that Axiom 4: "If a property is positive, then it is necessarily positive", is used in the proof of Theorem 3: ". If something is God-like, then the property of being God-like is an essence of that thing."
The argument assumes that something x is God-like and let φ be any property of x. φ must be positive, otherwise not-φ will be positive and thus x will have also not-φ: a contradiction.
By definition of "God-like", necessarily if φ is positive, anything which is God-like has φ. Hence, if necessarily φ is positive, then necessarily anything which is God-like has φ [by modal logic: from □(p ⇒ q) to □p ⇒ □q].
Now is the point where Axiom 4: "if φ is positive, necessarily φ is positive" is needed, to derive □P(φ) from P(φ).
Having derived □P(φ), we use it with "if necessarily φ is positive, then necessarily anything which is God-like has φ" to detach the consequent: □∀x[G(x) → φ(x)].
Thus, any property of x is entailed by the property of being God-like and so, by the definition of "essence," the property of being God-like is an essence of anything which has that property.
In addition to Fitting's very detailed technical exposition of the argument, we can see the 50 pages discussion of Sobel: Kurt Gödel’s Ontologischer Beweis, into Jordan Howard Sobel, Logic and theism: Arguments for and against beliefs in God (2009, Cambridge University Press).
